# How to do condition switch in jQuery stream, like .if().else().end();

Tags: jquery

```
$(...)
  .find(...)
  .if()
  .something
  .else()
  .otherthing
  .end();
```

if we can do this in jQuery, we don't need to do it in native javascript. it's more expressive.

Comment: i'm a newbie in jQuery.

Comment: There is nothing like this built into jQuery, you would have to build or find a plugin that does it. I've seen plugins that tried to implement this  in the past, but i don't quite understand why you think it would be more expressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if a has a class "class" else if has the id "#uniqueid" and at the end the default:

```
if( $('a').is('.class') ) {

} else if ($('a').is('#uniqueid')) {

} else {

}
```

The doc for .is():

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

You can write an if else statement. Use the following format

```
var sampleBoolean; //Assign this to something
//Ex: sampleBoolean = $("sampleDiv").is(":visible");

//Begin logic
if (!sampleBoolean) {
    //Do this
}
else {
    //Do this
}
//End logic
```